# How are files from a directory listed in Java?

Tags: java, file

I have a directory from which I need to read txt files.

Here is the code:

```
            try {
                File dir = new File(directoryName);
                File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        return name.endsWith(".txt");
                    }
                });
                for (File xmlfile : files) {
System.out.println("File name:" + xmlfile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

A test case was created thus:
1. A directory named "content" was created. It was populated with two files: 1.txt and 2.txt. These were created in the same order as they have been mentioned.
2. One of the files, 1.txt was renamed to sriram.txt (say).

Here are the results I got:
1. On Windows, the files were always listed alphabetically.
2. On Linux, the files were listed by timestamp. On Ubuntu, the files were listed in reverse order of the timestamps. On other Debian-based distros, the files were listed in ascending order of timestamp.

My question(s):
1. How does Java work internally to list the files? The documentation for `listFiles` and `FilenameFilter` are not clear on this.
2. It seems, from the above test case, that there is something OS-specific that Java is picking up on when listing files. What is this and how do I display it?

Comment: If there's nothing in the documentation, it means no order is guaranteed.

Comment: If you want a specific order, you'll have to sort the files yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) is absolutely clear on this:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

*(In most cases when you need file names to appear in a given order, you generally need to implement other orders too, so actually you aren't losing much by having to always sort the list manually.)*

Comment: Thanks. But I have run the same tests multiple times over (at least 500 times on Windows and maybe 50 times on Linux). The order is always the same (as already mentioned). Could it be that there is something OS-specific that forces the files to be returned in a specific order, time after time?

Comment: @Sriram In reality all Java does is ask the OS for a list of files. Whatever order the OS returns them in will be preserved. Most filesystems will probably return the same directory in the same order all the time, but there's no guarantee that all filesystems do that. And there's no guarantee that an OS won't rearrange them. And there's no guarantee that all OSes will return them in the same order. So basically: don't rely on any order, even if you tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't depend on any order on any system. If you need them in an order, you need to sort them.